# Can't get Autofac to resolve ObservableCollection<string>

Tags: autofac

I don't have much programming experience, so sorry if this is an obvious question.

See the following code. Autofac can resolve ObservableCollection<int>, but not ObservableCollection<string>.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource());

        using (var container = builder.Build())
        {
            // This line works.
            var x = container.Resolve<ObservableCollection<int>>();
            // This line throws exception: 
            // DependencyResolutionException was unhandled:
            // No constructors on type 'System.Char*' can be found 
            // with 'Public binding flags'.
            var y = container.Resolve<ObservableCollection<string>>();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Autofac 2.4.2 for .NET 4.0.

Any ideas?

**Update**:

It seems the problem is caused by:

```
builder.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource());
```

I replaced it with:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ObservableCollection<>))
       .As(typeof(ObservableCollection<>));
```

Now it works. But I still don't quite understand exactly why.

(sorry for my English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource` acts this way is that `ObservableCollection<string>` has a constructor that takes `string`. Since `string` is a concrete class type, the `AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegistereSource` will pick this up and try to resolve it. `System.String` however doesn't have any constructors that are callable, so you get the exception you are experiencing.

If you're just getting started with Autofac, I'd strongly recommend against `ACTNARS` - it only has a few use cases and most of them require the `predicate` parameter to be provided to avoid unexpected behaviour like the above.

What you've got now is the best way to go. A couple of pointers - the `As()` declaration is not necessary when the service type is the same as the concrete component type. Also, it is uncommon for `ObservableCollection<T>` to be used as a service at all - if you can provide some more details on your scenario, there might be a better way to express it with Autofac.